# How do I convert a reference to an integer (&usize) into an integer (usize)?

Tags: rust

I'm getting the following error:

```
the trait `std::slice::SliceIndex<[Pokemon]>` is not implemented for `&usize`
```

I'm trying to index my vector with a size parsed from user input.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself*

Comment: TL;DR the duplicate: `*my_reference`. You may wish to go back and re-read [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html) as it covers introductory topics like this.